# Brightness slider on top bar not working properly on laptop

Tags: 20.04, laptop, brightness

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 a couple weeks ago on my Matebook D14 with a Ryzen 5 and I realized that every time I turn on my laptop my brightness slider is set on the lowest brightness setting, but my display is on the highest brightness possible.
[image: In here my brightness slider is set on the lowest but my display has the highest bright possible]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your notebook? This will make it easier for someone to offer specific suggestions 